# Parsing Facebook wall data

Tags: php, facebook

I am looking for a solution where user posts on facebook wall (Personal wall or Our Company's Page wall) with particular tags. Then I want to parse the data and perform certain operations.

e.g.
user writes:

```
@<some_handler> please perform #task with #option, and #param etc.
```

Then app should be able to extract #task, #option and #params and perform some operation with certain response on user's wall [Assume User has already authorized our FB App to post on his wall]

Is this possible? How to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post information is available through the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). Once you have that, you should be able to parse the string for what you need.

Comment: +1, just retrieve the posts from the API (the page's `/feed` connection) and do whatever parsing you need on the results